# Problem increasing Popover width: no centered ion-popover

Tags: ionic-framework

I need to change my popover width and I’m using the –width property like the doc says.
The problem is that my popover is not centered in the middle of the page.

How is it possible to increase a popover width but having the popover centered? I would like to have the width at 80%/90% of the screen so I want use a modal.

[image]

This is my ionic version

```
"@ionic/core": "^5.3.1",
```

This is the code of how I call the popover:

```
 async openTicketPopover() {
const popover = await popoverController.create({
  component: 'app-tickets-popover',
  translucent: true,
});
return await popover.present();
```

}

And this is the popover structure (it's the same code of the documentation):

```
  <ion-content class="">
        <ion-card>

        </ion-card>
      </ion-content>
```

Comment: Please say what version of Ionic you're using and show some of your code. That will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: I've updated my answer, btw there is nothing more to see because it's a simple ion-content and a ion-card inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass the click event to the popover controller, then the popover will be positioned relative to the clicked element. If you don't pass the click event to the popover controller, then the popover will be absolutely positioned in the center of the viewport. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover#presenting

Important to note that changing the `--width` property on the fly in Chrome dev tools will have no effect because Ionic sets the width and absolute placement of the popover with JavaScript at the moment the click event happens.

It does sound like a modal might be a better UI component for your use case though. Your call.

Comment: I don't pass the event, btw the element don't stay at the center if I change --width. The problem remains with or without event.
I wouldn't like to use a modal because I don't want a full screen page.

Comment: My tests show it does stay in the center with `--width` changed https://jsfiddle.net/yajdm1bo/

Comment: Also, modals do have `--height` and `--width` properties as well so you can use a modal that doesn't cover the whole viewport.

Comment: Passing the class, like in your example, works. instead if I use ion-popover { --width: 80%; } there is the problem. So I used the cssClass when I create the popover.
Thank you for your example.

Comment: Glad I could help. Yeah that makes sense because of this explanation https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover#customization